# Finding direction of rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

I'm given matrix $A$ that represents a rotation. I can find the axis of rotation by solving $Av=v$. I can then determine the angle of rotation by taking $u$ such that $u\perp v$ and then computing $\theta$ via $u\cdot Au=|u||Au|cos(\theta).$

How do I then determine whether the rotation is clockwise or anti-clockwise?

Comment: This can’t be determined until you’ve first chosen an orientation for the rotation axis (which way is “up,” if you will). It’s meaningless to speak of the direction of rotation since it will be relative to this orientation. Even after doing this, you’ve still got to decide where your dividing line between clockwise and counterclockwise lies. After all, a counterclockwise rotation through $\theta$ is indistinguishable from a clockwise rotation through $2\pi-\theta$. Once you’ve made these choices, the answer below gives you a way to choose the correct angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sign of the shortest angle (which is in $(-\pi,\pi)$) is that of the triple product $v\cdot(u\times Au)$. (The cross product is a vector parallel to the axis, with the same or opposite orientation.)

Comment: What is the intuition to this? $u \times Au$ gives a vector parallel to $v$ right?

Comment: @Hamza: of course. Both $u$ and $Au$ are orthogonal to $v$.

Comment: Is it correct that if $u \times Au$ is in the same orientation as $v$, then the rotation is anti-clockwise?

Comment: @Hamza: it's one or the other, I don't know. Check cross-product on Wikipedia.

Comment: I might add that the direction of rotation can’t be determined without also assigning an orientation to the axis of rotation: both $v$ and $-v$ are eigenvectors of $A$ and are plausible choices of direction for the axis. It makes no sense to speak of rotation direction independently of this choice.

Comment: @amd: you could also add that it makes sense to define an orientation of the angle only if you take the shortest rotation, which never exceeds $\pi$ in absolute value. Because angles $\theta$ and $2\pi-\theta$ lead to the same final position, with rotations in opposite directions.

Comment: That’s also an arbitrary choice extrinsic to the rotation itself.